# How to update Rails partials at set intervals with $.ajax()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm building a sort-of clone of CoverItLive in Rails 3.1 and want to have the stream of comments automatically update. I'm using a partial in the view to display comments. There's a lot of info out there on doing UJS and AJAX wit forms or buttons or links in Rails, but I can't find any specific examples for what I need to do.

I'm assuming that `.ajax()` is the best approach, but I've never used it before and not sure if I need to provide `.js.erb` files when using this particular function? Could I just have the controller send `JSON` back to the client and go from there, or is there a better approach in rails?

This is what I'm thinking so far, based on what I read at another question:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: ''<%= comments_path(:json) %>'',
        data: {
            data: "comments_data"
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            if (result == "true"){
                alert("true");
            }else{
                alert("false");
            }
        }
    });
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative you should look into [Private Pub](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub), a gem that Ryan Bates has put togeather. See a screencast about it on [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub).

The trouble with your solution is now often you server will be hit unnecessarily, i guess it depends on the number of concurrent users you thing will be viewing this page.

if you do go down your route the .js.erb could just have a somthing like this in it:

```
$('#id_of_area_to_replace').html("<%= escape_javascript(render"comments/index") %>")
```

This would replace the whole area else you could just [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) new comments to the bottom of the area

Comment: The gem looks interesting, though I'm usually hesitant to add dependencies without a really good reason (beyond convenience) unless I take the time to understand how they work, but since it's Ryan I can at least count on it being mostly future-proof. I'll have to take the time to watch the Railscast.